# Integrate custom application metrics exposed from AWS Fargate Task to prometheus

Tags: prometheus, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate

I have a java application running as a task in AWS Fargate, this application exposes custom application metrics.

```
MaxwellMetrics_transaction_execution_time{quantile="0.5",} 0.0
```

Needs to integrate with Prometheus eventually. This is a 3rd party application and touching the code will be in the worst case. Logs are available in AWS Cloudwatch. Similarly, can we get the metrics in Cloud Watch?

*Additional info*

Whenever task is launched as FARGATE type, new set of public and private IP gets created and this application require making it down and bringing up, hence need better way to access /metric endpoint exposed. Using a metrics exporter requires changing source code to emit logs to store intermediate.

As mentioned this will be last choice.

Answer (score 0):

You said your metrics are available in CW. Have you considered using the [Prometheus CW exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/cloudwatch_exporter)?

Comment: metrics are exposed at application api endpoint not CW. My question is, how we can get the metrics in CW.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. How are these metrics exposed by your app? Are they spit to stdout? Are they available in a file? Are they available through a REST end-point? My uneducated guess would be that if you need to make them land in CW as custom metrics you'd need to write some logic to extract them and then `put` them to CW like [this](https://github.com/mreferre/fargatecount/blob/master/dockerAssets.d/fargatecount.sh#L44). Perhaps by running this logic as a sidecar to prevent changing your app?